# How to write RegEx to extract strings from an array in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, extract

How can I extract the name of the book, and the price of book from this array using Regular expression.

```
$bookList = array('PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition)' => 49.95,
          'Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript' => 37.33,
          'Beginning PHP and MySQL: From Novice to Professional' => 23.56,
          'Head First PHP & MySQL' => 64.35);
```

Is regEx'ing the function the best way to extract it?

```
function getBookName($bookList)
{
$bookRegEx = '';
$matchResult = array();
if (preg_match($bookRegEx, $bookList, $matchResult)) 
{
    return intval($matchResult[0]);
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: regex? wut? [isn't it just key (book) => value (price)?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: It's not clear what you want, nor why. Have you tried to `foreach` over the list? Which book entry do you want? Always the same one? And why strip the cents from the prices?

Comment: I want to extract all the names and then output them into tables. Yes basically a foreach statement would work, I just don't know how to separate name and price from each of the books in the array

Comment: @GivePie: You use foreach for exactly that. http://php.net/foreach Read the manual first, there is more in php than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex here. It really depends on how you want to use the array you have structured. I'd read up on how to use PHP arrays.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php is probably where you want to start.